# Self-induction in Transformer

Tags: electric-circuits, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

In a transformer,

> If the circuit of the secondary coil is opened, then the emf of the source equals the induced emf by self induction in primary coil

So what makes them equal? Is there a law that proves that or is it based on experiment or something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose there were resistance *R* in the primary circuit. Then the total emf in that circuit would drive current through that resistance. So
$$ \mathscr E_{source} - \mathscr E_{induced} = IR$$
Now let $R$ approach zero, and you have the relationship you asked about.

1. One might object that if we took  to zero,  might go to infinity. But even if $\mathscr E_{source}$ were constant, it would take an infinite time for this to happen, so it's fine to argue that if $R=0$ then $IR=0$.
2. Physically, $\mathscr E_{source} = \mathscr E_{induced}$ means that the energy supplied by the source per unit charge is being stored in the magnetic field in the transformer core.